# Connecting the iRig mic to a mixer or microphone input

Tags: audio-recording, microphone, iphone, input

I have a IK Multimedia iRig Mic that I want to plug into a standard TS 1/8 inch mono microphone connector (such as a computer).

The iRig mic has a iPhone 1/8 in connector (4 way), which transfers in and out of the iPhone.

How can I connect the iRig to a mono input?  I have tried just plug-in it directly, with no success.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Apple audio input ports are line-level, and PCs generally use SoundBlaster-style plug-in power TRS ports. So you need to find out what level the iRig outputs and then figure out how to match it with your mac or PC.

Comment: I also tried connecting it on a mixer microphone input (and adjusting the levels) and line input, without success.

Comment: you might try using some alligator clips to try connecting the tip and various rings to the tip and ring on a 3.5mm or 1/4" cable. If you can't find a schematic, you might be able to figure out the signals that way.

Answer (score 2):

I picked up a Smartphone Headset To PC Adapter and it works with an iRig.  Here's one on amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/Smartphone-Headset-PC-Adapter-01-PH35-PC35/dp/B008OB2NHA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008OB2NHA)

Answer (score 1):

I found the Apple connector has the microphone signal on the sleeve ring and second ring. That explain why it does not work out of the box.

I can't find any adapter on the market for that. However it seems relatively easy to:

- cut the wire before the existing connector
- install a TS 1/8 mono male connector on the microphone end
- install a TS 1/8 mono female connector on the existing connector end

That way, I will still be able to use the iRig mic on a iPhone by using the existing connector, and also plug the microphone on any 1/8 mono input by using the TS 1/8 mono male connector I installed.

Schema:

```
[MIC]----------cut-here------[iRig TRRS 1/8  Connector]
[MIC]---------[TS 1/8 Male]    <---->     [TS 1/8 Female]----[iRig TRRS 1/8 Connector]
```